# how to install react-native-onesignal using cocoapods ???

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm confused, after detaching the application with Expokit, I have to install dependencies with cocoapods. Now I want to use oneSignal with react-native-onesignal but when I bind using

> react-native link react-native-onesignal

. I have dependency issues. react-native-onesignal can not detect the React library. I understood that it had to be installed using cocoapods. When I add

> pod 'react-native-onesignal',: path =>
>   "../node_modules/react-native-onesignal"

and I do pod install. I get the No podspec error for `react-native-onesignal` in`../ node_modules / react-native-onesignal`. I do not understand. How can I install ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cocoapod is just a package manager for ios 3rd party libraries. Can you follow these steps

1. npm install --save react-native-onesignal
2. add the following to your podfile

> ```
> pod 'OneSignal', '~> 1.13.3'
> ```
>
> 3. execute  `cd ios && pod install`

4. react-native link react-native-onesignal

i hope your issue will be solved

Answer (score 0):

i found the podspec on github  https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/blob/master/react-native-onesignal.podspec and i add in my podfile

> pod 'react-native-onesignal', :git => "https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal.git"

after

> pod install

This solution works well too.

`